# Open new tab terminal reset gemset by rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bash, gemset

When I open terminal then enter to the rails application, the rvm will load the gemset in `.ruby-gemset` file as the following:

```
> cd my_application/ 
> rvm gemset list
```

The output as the following:

```
gemsets for ruby-2.2.2 (found in /home/yakout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2)
   (default)
=> my_gemset
   global
```

Then I open new tab in terminal, and run `rvm gemset list`, the output will be:

```
gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /home/yakout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
=> (default)
   global
```

I put the  following line in `.profile` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

And I put the following lines in `.bash_profile` file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

And I put the following line in `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

And I changed the preferences of my terminal by: `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Title and Command` tab -> `Run command as a login shell`.

How can I make `rvm` load the current gemset when I open new tab in terminal ?

Comment: 5 years later I still have this pb :/

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround to get the right gemset when you open a new tab.
Add this line at the end of your ~/.profile

```
cd .
```

I got this from https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2527

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply adding two files in your application directory. with the following name :

.ruby-gemset

.ruby-version

Inside .ruby-gemset just mention your gemset name

Inside .ruby-version just mention your ruby version

Answer (score 0):

So you want it to be your default even when you're not in an application? I would use:

```
 rvm --default use 2.2.2@my_gemset
```

Comment: It doesn't work also, when I open new tab, it's return to `default`

Comment: if setting the default doesn't work, i'd rvm implode, start over, remove everything rvm related from your dotfiles, etc.